# why should we add this while calling a method in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I  am having a class based component in react,the following is a piece of code 
which uses es7 syntax so that i can access my variables of my class without binding this

```
inputChangedHandler = (event, inputIdentifier) => {
        console.log(we are inside the inputhandler)
       };
```

According to my knowledge inputChangeHandler in a method from es7 syntax

```
  <Input
changed={this.onChangedHandler}/>
/>
```

In these lines i am passing my  inputChangeHandler as props to my component

Following things i tried to search but i didn't find any help please help me

1) According to my knowledge  we never used this for calling a method inside a class but why did we even use this for calling onChangeInputHandler

2) Where  are  we assigning memory to the methods which we create in react

```
  class A {

    b (){
        console.log("we are inside the b method")
    }
}

var a = new A()
a.b()
we are inside the b method
```

Following is my javascript code which i created a method inside class and accessed it without this

Comment: that's how classes work in javascript

Comment: Now i edited my question once go through please suggest me what i have missed while learning thanks

Comment: Tl;DR - your example is unrelated to the code in the beginning of your question - to access class property within a class instance one uses `this` - your *example* `a.b()` of course doesn't use `this` but if you had `c() {}` method inside `class A` returning function `b` it would need to `return this.b` not `return b`

Comment: If we are accessing a method inside another method then we should use this

Comment: yes, that is what I said